# How to read multiple SQLite tables in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables in a SQlite database -- avg_ep, EL, and mrg_ep.

I can read each table into the pandas dataframe by the following codes.

```
 with engine.connect()as con:
         avg_ep=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM avg_ep", engine)
         EL=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM EL", engine)
         mrg_ep=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM mrg_ep", engine)
```

Is there a simple way to read all the tables at once?

Comment: take a look at `UNION` to combine the results of multiple queries.

Comment: Also, depending on the contents of the tables (i.e., do they have a common index field), you may want to join them via SQL, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. You can also use SQLAlchemy to join them. If you share the column names for each table, we can help with that.